# Animation and 2-way binding

Tags: wpf, binding, slider, dependency-properties, wpf-animation

I'm playing with WPF animation and faced a weird problem.

I have a `Slider` and a `TextBox`. TextBox is bound to Slider.Value using 2-way binding:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="MySlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="50" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MySlider, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Test</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

When I drag slider, text in textbox changes. When I change text in textbox, value of slider is updated, it works correctly.

Now I add an animation, which animates Slider.Value property to 0. I start it on button press.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation();

    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    animation.To = 0;

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, MySlider);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(Slider.ValueProperty));

    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
     
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

When I press button, animation scrolls Slider to 0. TextBox is also changes to 0 synchronously with slider.

And now I face the problem. After animation I cannot change text in the TextBox. I change text, move focus, and the text with slider value resets to 0. I still can move the Slider, and the TextBox updates with the Slider value. But I can't set the Slider value using the TextBox.

I think when animation stops, the value somehow freezes on a value, specified in the `animation.To` property, but I can't figure how to unfreeze it. Or maybe it is something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because of dependency property value precedence, meaning that value set by animation has higher "priority" than value set via binding.

Here is a quote from MSDN on how to workaround this:

> One way to regain control of an
>   animated property in code is to use
>   the BeginAnimation method and specify
>   null for the AnimationTimeline
>   parameter. For more information and an
>   example, see [How to: Set a Property
>   After Animating It with a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx).